# Uninstall Imagick Version that PHP is using

Tags: php, imagick

I installed Imagick through `apt-get install`. However the version it installed was old (6.9.7) and does not have all the delegates I need built in.

So I thought I uninstalled it using `apt-get remove --purge imagemagick` and reinstalled it from source.

Currently `identify -version` gives me the correct version I just installed (6.9.12) however `php -r "print_r(Imagick::getVersion());"` still shows v 6.9.7.

```
facepalm
      .-'---`-.
    ,'          `.
    |             \
    |              \
    \           _  \
    ,\  _    ,'-,/-)\
    ( * \ \,' ,' ,'-)
     `._,)     -',-')
       \/         ''/
        )        / /
       /       ,'-'
```

My questions are

- Why?
- How do I remove the old version?
- How do I update the path for php to use the newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick is split up into a few packages, with both the `php-imagick` extension package and the front facing `imagemagick` package using libraries provided by the `libmagick*` packages.

If you've already got the compiled version of ImageMagick in place, the simplest thing will be to remove the packaged version of `imagick` and then compile the `imagick` extension as well, configuring it to use your freshly compiled version of ImageMagick.

Building on the instructions [here](https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-compile-and-install-php-extensions-from-source/), you can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y php-imagick
git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick.git
pushd imagick
phpize
./configure --with-imagick=${IMAGEMAGICK_PREFIX_DIR}
make
sudo cp modules/imagick.so ${PHP_EXTENSION_DIR}
echo extension=imagick.so | sudo tee ${PHP_CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH}/conf.d/30-imagick.ini
```

Where:

- `IMAGEMAGICK_PREFIX_DIR` is the prefix into which you've installed ImageMagick (such that `MagickWand-config` can be found at `${IMAGEMAGICK_PREFIX_DIR}/bin/MagickWand-config`).
- `PHP_EXTENSION_DIR` is the directory where PHP looks for its extensions, and can be found via `php -i | grep extension_dir`. This looks something like `/usr/lib/php/20190902`.
- `PHP_CONFIGURATION_FILE_PATH` is the base directory of the particular SAPI configuration, and can be found via `php -i | grep 'Configuration File (php.ini) Path'` (for the `cli` SAPI) or the value listed under `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` in the `phpinfo()` output via the webserver. This looks something like `/etc/php/7.4/${SAPI}`, where SAPI is `cli`, or `apache2`, etc.

Comment: You sir are both a scholar and an gentleman! Much appreciated!

Comment: I wish i can upvote many times. Thank you Thank you. I compiled the ImageMagick from source but php extension was not recognizing the newly build library, your solution worked like a charm.